# SSAS Integrated Environment for Tabular projects

Tags: ssas, environment, tabular, integrated

I am making use of Analysis Services Tabular Project in Integrated Environment all within Visual Studio Professional 2019. It all works well however, my question is: How do I distribute the "Integrated Environment" result of the Tabular project to other users in the company (say for instance in Excel) ?

Or, will it only be possible for other users on the Active Directory domain to access a Tabular project when it is on an SSAS Server Instance ?